# why does using this.store.find to load a single model force me to use content.attributeName in the template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can't understand this.

In my route I have:

```
   model: function (params) {
      return this.store.find('article', params.article_id);
   }
```

And in my template I cannot just output my article's attributes like this: {{title}}
but I have to use {{content.title}}

Likewise when I'm in my create article route and I create a model like this:

```
 model: function () {
   return this.store.createRecord('article', {title: '', pageContent: '', urlSegment: ''});
 }
```

I'm having to bind the inputs like this:

```
{{input type="text" value=content.title id="title" placeholder="Title"}}
```

But, when I'm loading an index route like this

```
model: function () {
        return this.store.find('article');
    }
```

In my template I am able to just say {{#each}} {{title}} {{/each}} and it is much nicer, I don't want to have to use content. for every item route. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

*EDIT* 
As of the latest versions - ember 1.7 and ember data 1.0000.9 I can substitute content for model, but I still can't address the attributes directly.

Comment: i would like to know how this works as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And in my template I cannot just output my article's attributes like this: {{title}} but I have to use {{content.title}}

Judging by this, you're not setting up your controller properly. You're likely inheriting from `Ember.Controller` instead of `Ember.ObjectController`. `Ember.ObjectController` will proxy properties to your model, so you can use just `{{title}}`.

Also, don't use the `content` property in controllers, use the `model` property. You'll run into a whole lot of subtle bugs if you use the former.

[Here's](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zasaw/1/edit?html,js,output) a JSBin showing that behavior.

Comment: that was it, for whatever reason my controllers were set to just extend from Ember.Controller thank you very much, i had wondered this for so long

Comment: i learned the reason  I had set them this way, I started with older versions last december and a bunch of learning + issues + flux had left me with that, now it's fixed